# Encrypt password on VBA password box

Tags: excel, vba, encryption

I have a couple of userforms for my excel spreadsheet and I need to setup an admin panel for certain tasks that I don't want most people to access.

The problem I have is that I can setup a simple password protection form however the text is always visible. I want to try and encrypt it so if anyone is looking over my should or one of the other admins shoulders then they cannot see the password.

Is there anyway to have the text appear as ******** or something similar?

Thanks
Al

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim MyValue As Variant
MyValue = InputBox("Enter Password")
     If MyValue = "lemonade" Then 'lemonade being the password
     Application.Visible = True
     Else
    MsgBox ("Password Incorrect")
End If
End Sub
```

Edit - I have amended it to follow your suggestion as I had it to bring up an input box instead of creating my own userform.

```
If Pword2.Value = "lemonade" Then
AddPick1.Hide
Report1.Hide
Unload Me
Admin1.Show vbModal
Else
MsgBox ("Password Incorrect")
End If
```

When the password is incorrect it gives the incorrect password error however when it is correct it gives me the following error (Must close of hide topmost modal form first) However I have it to set to hide all other forms before loading the Admin1 form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the TextBox properties there is a property called PasswordChar.  Enter your preferred 'hidden' character in here.

You can also add a button to your form to reveal the password if you wish using the Mouse-Up and Mouse
_Down events.  MouseDown would look like the following on a textbox called TextBox1 and using a button called CommandButton1:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    TextBox1.PasswordChar = vbNullChar
End Sub
```

I'll leave you to code the Mouse_Up event.

[This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278486(v=office.15).aspx) will give you the usage but you will find plenty of examples with a Google search.

Comment: Thanks for that @barryleajo I have followed that but im now getting a Modal error. I have amended the code & how it loads. PS sorry for being a pain haha

Comment: Don't use InputBox, just create a TextBox for the password on the existing userform.